# Android - BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast

Tags: android, bootcompleted

I am trying to catch the BOOT_COMPLETED intent. In my receiver, I just print something to the Log. In Logcat I get this error, and the log statement that I put never prints out. I have set the permission in the manifest for

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

And have also declared the required intent filter in my receiver. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your application installed to sd-card or to internal memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

That's impossible to answer given the limited information you have supplied. Perhaps your action string is wrong in your `<intent-filter>`.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemEvents/OnBoot) that does just what you describe (boot-time receiver writing a message to LogCat).

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem too, found this answer and solved it by diffing with CommonsWare's sample code:

You will get this error, when you call setResultData(...) in the onReceive()-Method of the BroadcastReceiver and reacting to a non-ordered Broadcast. It looks like the boot broadcast is non-ordered. see also: [Developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#setResultData%28java.lang.String%29)

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    try
    {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);                
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
            // setResultData(null);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```